# Telerik rad gantt does not add task

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad

I have a Rad Gantt control in my `ASP.net` page. As you can see in the code and every thing looks good when I run the web page in server.

But when I click on "Add Task" button to work with this control, it starts an endless progress and stop on loading.

Can any one help me about this?

```
<telerik:RadGantt RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadGantt1" DataSourceID="Sqld1" Height="600px" ListWidth="350px"
            DependenciesDataSourceID="dependata" SelectedView="WeekView" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GanttBoundColumn DataField="Title" DataType="String" Width="120px"></telerik:GanttBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GanttBoundColumn DataField="Start" DataType="DateTime" DataFormatString="dd/MM/yy" Width="40px"></telerik:GanttBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GanttBoundColumn DataField="End" DataType="DateTime" DataFormatString="dd/MM/yy" Width="40px"></telerik:GanttBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
             <DataBindings>
                <TasksDataBindings
                    IdField="ID" ParentIdField="ParentID"
                    StartField="Start" EndField="End"
                    OrderIdField="OrderID"
                    SummaryField="Summary"
                    TitleField="Title" PercentCompleteField="PercentComplete" />
                <DependenciesDataBindings
                    TypeField="Type" IdField="ID"
                    PredecessorIdField="PredecessorID"
                    SuccessorIdField="SuccessorID" />
            </DataBindings>
        </telerik:RadGantt>
```

Comment: Does the problem happen in all browsers?

Comment: Is there a JavaScript error on the page?
If there is an AjaxManager or panel set its EnableAjax property to false and test again. Check for errors too in the console.

Comment: i have tested different ways. i think that i faced this problem because of using Rad schedular & rad gantt together in a single page. is this Possible???